# powershell split using wildcard

Tags: powershell, split, wildcard

I am attempting to split a text file using the PowerShell -split operator, but unable to figure out the expression.

example

[image]

this needs to be split into a total of 4 section e.g.

[image]

while the first 2 sections work as expected, the 3rd section can be text with spaces OR text with no spaces OR numbers of a variable length which does not work for me.

```
$c -split "(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d),\s(\d\d\:\d\d)\s\-\s*"
```

[image]

```
$c -split "(\d\d/\d\d/\d\d),\s(\d\d\:\d\d)\s\-\s(*\:\s)"
```

[image]

splits it into 3 and unable to split it into 4 as the * seems to override the 4th section

any suggestions how to fix this would be much appreciated

Comment: Could you use plain text for your _example_ and _expected output_ instead of screenshots? It will be easier for others trying to help you if they can copy what you already have.

Comment: i did initially but the formatting was messed up so edited and posted an image. will post the example in the comments

Comment: 16/01/18, 00:47 - John Doe: Payload_Text
23/01/18, 14:27 - JaneDoe: Payload_Text
16/01/18, 00:47 - Jack the Rabbit: Payload_Text
23/01/18, 14:27 - 12 345 67890: Payload_Text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regex *alternation* (`|`) to specify multiple (multi-character) separator strings:

```
'16/01/18, 00:47 - John Doe: Payload_Text' -split ', | - |: '
```

Note that the regex you pass to the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) specifies what *separates* the tokens rather than what matches the tokens themselves.

(Enclosing (parts of) the regex in `(...)`, i.e. including *capture groups*, makes `-split` *include* the captured text in the output, but  your sample data doesn't require matching any parts of the tokens themselves).

Note that if you have an *array* of input strings, you'll have to call `-split` on each in a *loop*, as direct use of `-split` will return a *single, flat array* containing the tokens across all input strings.